# Viewing the properties of the selected product with the woocommerce rest api

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I created a form in the list of products linked to the id number, but I don't know how to bring it up. Can you help me?
My product form list;

```
<?php $i = 1; ?>
<?php foreach ( $data as $row ) : ?>
<td><?= $i; ?></td>
<td><?= $row['name']; ?></td>   
<form action="single_product.php" name="update" method="GET">
<td><input type="submit" name="edit" value="<?= $row['id']; ?>"/></td></form>
<?php $i++; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

single_product.php

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('http://localhost/api-woocommerce/single_product_connect.php');
$data = json_decode($data, true);////I get an undefined error when I print this array as foreach
?>
//I don't know what to write here in array because foreach ( $data as $row ) komutunu kullandığımda"I'm getting an undefined foreach error"
```

single_product_connect.php

```
<?php
$id = $_get['edit'];?>
<?php echo json_encode($woocommerce->GET('products'.$id)); ?>
```

screen;
[image]